# How to configure proxy settings in GeForce Experience?

Tags: graphics-card, proxy, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I connect to the internet through a proxy.

But after repeated searching I couldn't find a way to make the GeForce Experience in my computer to connect to the internet (basically I could not set up the proxy settings in it).

I can update the drivers directly from Nvidia's website but I cannot go past the login screen in the GeForce Experience software.

Is there any way to change the proxy settings in the software ?

Comment: Are you sure the application doesn't use the proxy settings of the OS?  If it does not, and there is no way to to set the proxy settings on the application, then you are simply out of luck.  You should verify if the application is even attempting to send/recieve traffic.  If you are behind a commercial firewalls the traffic is likely simply blocked.

Comment: @Ramhound I am quite positive that the application does not use proxy setting of the OS (not fully sure though !). But how to possibly verify whether the application is attempting to send/receive traffic ?

Answer (score 7):

## No.

Not even now. Every time I need to install something from Nvidia at work that requires network connectivity, I need to switch my dev rig from my work line to a different ISP entirely to avoid proxies.

They completely lock down all UI options until you've signed in (which you can't do behind a proxy!) and even after you've "unlocked" access to it, you still can't set the proxy within any of the menu settings.

I had to deal with this for CUDA and GeForce Experience software.

I was incredulous when I couldn't get CUDA to install without the offline installer, but *everything*? I'm a little embarrassed for Nvidia...

You can check out this forum post starting in 2014 and last updated in 2017 (at the time I'm writing this): https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/671097/internet-connection-via-proxy/

Comment: Still not on 2021. An overrated company.

Comment: @wonsuc I love how customer support is blaming the complexities of "the cloud" for lack of updates. Meanwhile for the last 10+ years researchers, engineers, technicians, and gamers, all stuck behind firewalls are still stymied by lack of basic proxy support.